# passing datas with relationship in the view laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-blade

if i have this models relationship

- Claims : this table hasMany(Refunds)
- Refunds: with data of various request. this table belongsTo(Claims) AND belongsToMany(Services)
- Services: with list of services. this table belongsToMany(Refunds)
- Refunds-Services: bridge table for refunds and services

Claims model

```
   class Claims extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'dossier',
        'date_cla',
    ];

    public function refunds()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Refunds::class);
        }               
}
```

Refunds model

```
class Refunds extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'date_ref',
        'status_ref',
    ];

    public function services()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Services::class)->withPivot(['services_id','services_amount','services_status']);
        }       

    public function claims()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Claims::class,'claims_id');
        }           

}
```

Services model

```
   class Services extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'code',
        'name',
    ];

    public function refunds()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Refunds::class);
    }

}
```

and in my controller this method

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
        $dossier = request('dossier');
        $claim = Claims::with('refunds')
        ->where('dossier', '=', $dossier)->first();

        $

        $view = view('pages.modify', compact('claim'));
        $sections = $view->renderSections()['table'];
        return $sections;
    }
```

how can insert in the Controller the relationship between Refunds and Service to use the pivot (service_amount is in the Refunds-Services table)

```
<li>- {{ $item->pivot->services_amount }}</li>
```

Because now in the view cannot see this relationship
Thx

Comment: Please write the code of your relationships as in your model 

Comment: did it :) i need somthing like  $claim = Claims::with('refunds')->with('services) that are connected but this dont work

Comment: Maybe somthing REFUNDS::WITH(SERVICES) where dossiers ( in claims ) is my parameter ? .....

Comment: please try `Claims::with('refunds.services')` it will eager load your services and your pivot as well

Comment: I belive there is a DB design error. I think you should only have one claim for one service and one refund for one claim. On long run I think it's too difficult to manage all those many to many relationships in an effective way.

Comment: I have a claim associated to One assurance policy but many refunds that are many request of insurance benefits that a customer can ask in different times on the same refund request. Services are list of insurance benefits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Nested Eager Loading**

```
$claim = Claims::with('refunds.services')
    ->where('dossier', '=', $dossier)->first();
```

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax. For example, let's eager load all of the book's authors and all of the author's personal contacts in one Eloquent statement:
>
> `$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();`